# How can I insert data into a checkboxlist as a hyperlink?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a function that looks like this:

```
Private Sub displayData(title As String, cost As String, asin As String)
    cdCheckList.Items.Add(title + "/" + cost + "/" + asin)
End Sub
```

I want to make the entire string (title + "/" + cost + "/" + asin) a hyperlink to another page called `SearchDisplay.aspx`.

EDIT: I need to send the the values of `title`, `cost`, and `asin` to the other page as well.

Not totally sure how this can be done.  Can someone help me out?

Comment: Wow, i don't mean to criticize, just a little world colliding experience... Everytime i see stuff like this, coming from Java or .Net guys, i clinch a bit. From a Semantic and Usability point of view, this is awful, i can understand it's not the point here just a commnt4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have Visual Studio to hand but could you try:

```
Private Sub displayData(title As String, cost As String, asin As String)
    cdCheckList.Items.Add("<a href=\"SearchDisplay.aspx\">" + title + "/" + cost + "/" + asin + "</a>")
End Sub
```

or using `String.Format` would look nicer and easier to read:

```
Private Sub displayData(title As String, cost As String, asin As String)
    cdCheckList.Items.Add(String.Format("<a href=\"SearchDisplay.aspx\">{0}/{1}/{2}</a>", title, cost, asin))
End Sub
```

**Updated to answer OP's re-phrased question:**

```
Private Sub displayData(title As String, cost As String, asin As String)
    cdCheckList.Items.Add(String.Format("<a href=\"SearchDisplay.aspx?title={1}&cost={2}&asin={2}\">{0}/{1}/{2}</a>", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(title), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(cost), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(asin)))
End Sub
```

You should always encode URL query string parameters. You should look at using Microsoft's AntiXss library instead of the HttpUtility class. You can find out more information on the AntiXss library [here](http://wpl.codeplex.com/).

Comment: I don't think I was clear in my first post.  What I need to do is make that a hyperlink to SearchDisplay.aspx AND send title, cost, and asin as query's (or query strings... not sure on the terminology)

Comment: I'm getting an error saying "Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Format' can be called with these arguements."

Comment: I got it!  Took your command and just had to rearrange some quotation marks :)  Thanks!